# Unauthorized response with Invalid Audience error for Azure AD + ASP.Net Core 2.1

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, bearer-token

I have developed an UI and Web API using ASP.net Core 2.1 with Azure AD authentication. Both are registered with Azure App registration. I am using below code in UI. But I am getting an Unauthorized error.

```
string AZURE_AD_INSTANE = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
string TENANT_ID = "<tenant GUID>";
string CLIENT_ID = "<Client GUID ofWeb API>";
string SECRET = "<Secret created for Web API under Certificates & secrets>";
string RESOURCE = "https://MyOrg.onmicrosoft.com/TestWebAPI"; //Application ID URI set in Expose an API
ClientCredential ClientCredential = new ClientCredential(CLIENT_ID, SECRET);
string authority = String.Format("{0}{1}", AZURE_AD_INSTANE, TENANT_ID);


AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
string accessToken = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(RESOURCE, ClientCredential).Result.AccessToken;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:44326/api/values/Get");
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

string status = response.StatusCode.ToString();
```

StartUp.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options)); 
       services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

[image]

I am getting a access token. When I check in jwt.io, it says 'Signature Verified'. But the API call gives unauthorized response status code. When I check the response header, it has the information as "{Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience is invalid"}"

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I need you to provide a screenshot, go to aad>your app>Expose an API to provide a screenshot.

Comment: @Carl, I have provided the screenshot as you asked. Please check it and let me know your suggestion.

Comment: In the response, I am getting the error as "{Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience is invalid"}" for response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate

Answer (score 0):

Ensure https://MyOrg.onmicrosoft.com/TestWebAPI is registered as a valid audience in your WebAPI:

```cs
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidAudiences = new List<string> 
        {
            "https://MyOrg.onmicrosoft.com/TestWebAPI",
            "..."
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I have updated my post with Startup class "ConfigureServices()" method. It already contains AddAzureADBearer. If I replace it with your "AddJwtBearer" code, I am getting internal server error. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: @Kattesang AddJwtBearer is internally called by AddAzureADBearer. You need to recover and configure the registered IOptions<JwtBearerOptions>.